# Get user favorite posts thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a user's favorited post as thumbnail.
Currently using this code:

```
<?php
    $post_id = array( get_user_favorites($user_id, $site_id));
    $loop = new WP_Query( $post_id ); 
    if($loop->have_posts()):
        while ( $loop->have_posts()): 
            $loop->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : // thumbnail check 
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id());                                  

?>
            <div>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image[0]); ?>" />
            </div>
<?php

            endif; 
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This display ALL my blog post as thumbnail but not FAVORITED post.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_favorites()` (https://favoriteposts.com/) is going to return an array of post IDs.

You're wrapping those post IDs in an array and attempting to pass them into WP_Query. You need to specify which parameter you're attempting to set with those IDs which in this case would be 'post__in'.

```
/**
 * I'm assuming based on the code in your question that you
 * have access to $user_id and $site_id already.
 */
$post_ids = get_user_favorites( $user_id, $site_id );

/**
 * We only want to attempt to display the favorite post images
 * IF favorites are set.
 */
if ( $post_ids ) {
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'      => -1, // display all favorited posts. Perhaps limit?
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'post__in'            => $post_ids
    ) ); 

    // Output here...
}
```

I'm referencing both the documentation at the plugin homepage and the gist provided in their code samples: https://gist.github.com/kylephillips/9fe12f195c671c989af3